# What's the best way to limit tags in a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: php, javascript, wysiwyg

limitation of tags in a wysiwyg editor by excluding buttons is completly not enough, because i still can copy a page content and past it in the editor, and... it's will accept it !

i want some solution to limit the allowed tags, by example i love the way stackoverflow limit it by the traditional way of *** and quotes, but i don't want this style , i still like the wisiwyg's Real-time editing.

Note : If it's impossible, how i can do that in the php script which receive the html ?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of editor are you talking about? A desktop editor, or one embedded into a web site?

Comment: SO uses Markdown afaik if that is of any help to you. See http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to processing the tags you would like to remove. The [fckEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fckeditor/) does something very similar to your requirement when it pastes the clipboard contents as unformatted text. As it is open source, I think you can get some inspiration from it or even use it if it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

User [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to filter the submitted content.  I wouldn't recommend allowing submitted content without that tool.